# Unexpected behaviour with Java timer task

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

My Timer task is not functioning as it's supposed to. I have scheduled it to repeat a specific task every 3 seconds but this is not happening.

As per Java documentations:

> schedule(TimerTask task, long delay,long period) .
>   Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.

```
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        log.info("Schedule task");
        Timer time = new Timer();

        TesterClient tc = new TesterClient();
        time.schedule(tc, 0, 3000);
    }
}


public class TesterClient extends TimerTask {
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("New Task!!!!");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
    }
}
```

And yet i only get one "New Task!!!!" printed in console

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

**Update:**

I will try to paste in here every piece of code that is relevant and goes from top to bottom in terms of execution.

Start:

```
public class Tester {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.manager.ManagerClient");
    public static Timer time = new Timer();

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        log.info("Creating service");
        Service.serviceInit();  

        log.info("Initializing TesterClient for scheduled task");
        TesterClient tc = new TesterClient();
        time.schedule(tc, 0, 3000);
    }
    public static ManagerSettings managerSettings() {
        ManagerSettings managerSettings = new ManagerSettings();
        managerSettings.setName("managerClient");
        managerSettings.setHost("77.237.251.152");
        managerSettings.setPort(5038);
        managerSettings.setUsername("orderlystats");
        managerSettings.setPassword("orderlystats");

        return managerSettings;
    }   
}

Service class method:

static ExecutorService executorService; 
    {
        serviceInit();
    }

    //public static ClassLoader loader;

    public static void serviceInit(){
        if(executorService!=null) {
            return;
        }
        executorService= Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        try {
            ThreadPoolExecutor tpe=(ThreadPoolExecutor)executorService;
            tpe.setMaximumPoolSize(100000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

package com.orderlysoftware.testing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.OrderlyCalls;
import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.asterisk.manager.ManagerClient;
import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.asterisk.manager.action.ManagerResponse;
import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.asterisk.manager.event.ManagerEvent;
import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.asterisk.manager.event.ManagerEventListener;
import com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.base.Service;

public class TesterClient extends TimerTask {

    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.orderlysoftware.orderlycalls.manager.ManagerClient");
    public static ExecutorService es = Service.getExecutorService();

    public ManagerClient mc;

    public void init() {    
        log.info("run check method to see if Manager Client is running");
        boolean running = check();

        log.info("checker status is : " + running);
        while(running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                startCall();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                log.info("Sleep interrupted");
            }
        }   
    }
    public boolean check() {
        log.info("ManagerClient is: " + mc);
        if(mc == null) {
            log.info("Initialize service");
            mc = (ManagerClient)OrderlyCalls.createService(ManagerClient.class, Tester.managerSettings());
            log.info("Initialize ManagerClient");
            mc.init();
            log.info("Service created. ManagerClient initialized : "+ mc);
        }
        if(!mc.isConnected()) {
            log.info("ManagerClient is not connected");         
            return false;
        }
        log.info("Check if ManagerClient is connected AND running");
        if(mc.isConnected() && !mc.isRunning()) {
            log.info("Manager Client is connected but NOT running");
            return false;
        }
        if(mc.isConnected() && mc.isRunning()) {
            log.info("ManagerClient is connected and running");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private void startCall() {
        log.info("Adding listener to the call");
        addListenerToCall(mc);

        int testID = 0;
        ManagerResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = mc.originate("Local/1001@main", "1001", "main", "1", null, null, 2500, "1002", "testID=" + (testID++), "1", true);
            log.info("Manager response is: " + response);
            if(response == null) {
                mc.shutdown();
                throw new IOException("Null response for originate.");              
            }
            if(!response.getValue("Response").equals("Success")) {
                mc.shutdown();
                throw new IOException("Originate returned " + response.getValue("Response") + ": " + response.getValue("Message"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("IO Exception" + e.toString());
        }
    }   
    public void addListenerToCall(ManagerClient mc) {       
        try {
            // Add event listener 
            log.info("Adding ManagerEventListener to ManagerClient: " + mc);
            mc.addManagerEventListener(new ManagerEventListener() {         
                @Override
                public void handleManagerEvent(ManagerEvent event) {
                    if("OriginateResponse".equals(event.getType())) {
                        handleOriginateResponse(event);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.info("IO Exception : " + e);
        }       
    }
    protected void handleOriginateResponse(ManagerEvent event) {
        try {
            // do something here 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.info("sleep interupted" + e);
        }           
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        log.info("New Task!!!!!!!!!!");
        init(); 
    }   
}
```

Comment: prints every 3sec for me

Comment: works for me too. is there some context we can't see?

Comment: Works for me too. just copy pasted your code.

Comment: This is weird but it does not work for me.... @HaroldShip There is more code but its inside init method and further down the line, which is not really applicable in this case because the methods down the line should be called in init() anyway.

Comment: Given that no one else can reproduce this, please give an absolutely complete example - currently you don't have imports and we don't know what 'log' is, for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet as per your request i have included absolutely complete example ;).

Comment: Can you add a Thread.sleep before the end of the main method to see if this is caused by the JVM exiting?

Comment: @AlexanderTorstling adding sleep did not make any difference, the program was / is running but only run once and not repeatedly

Comment: That's not a complete example. There's a whole bunch of code we don't have. The idea is to provide something as short as possible that lets us copy, paste, compile, run and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see what you mean, but this will not really be possible as the packages/classes that i am using are huge (and i mean it) and the code in the packages uses other code and so on, so on... + its not really code that can be disclosed ;). I was just hoping that by looking at what i have provided you will have at least some idea why this may be running once.

Comment: I didn't ask for you to post what your confidential, large code. I asked you to post a short but complete example that demonstrates the problem. You should take your original code, and cut it down bit by bit, removing pieces until *either* you find the issue, or you end up with something that can be posted as a complete example demonstrating the problem. See http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry fer getting back so late, i just went the route you have suggested and as i was trimming down the code to post on SO i have actually found the problem :)

Comment: @MaciejCygan: That's often the case - that's why it's always a good idea to do that diagnosis first. I know it takes a while, but it's a good thing nonetheless :)

Comment: @JonSkeet And the problem was actually that the while loop in init() method was never broken, hence the timer run only once waiting for the loop to finish but this never happened as the 'running' variable was only set once and never checked again in the loop. Hence the object never terminated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works for me - but I suspect the problem is that you're letting the `Timer` get garbage collected:

> After the last live reference to a Timer object goes away and all outstanding tasks have completed execution, the timer's task execution thread terminates gracefully (and becomes subject to garbage collection). However, this can take arbitrarily long to occur.

As noted in comments, I *believe* that "outstanding tasks" means "tasks that have already been started" rather than just "ones which would be scheduled". The docs are unclear, however, and I may be mistaken.

If you prevent garbage collection (e.g. by keeping a reference to the `Timer` in a static variable) then I think you'll see it keep going forever...

Comment: how do you understand `all outstanding tasks have completed execution` in this case?

Comment: @SergeyPauk: I understand it to mean all tasks that have been started - *not* ones that will occur later on due to scheduling. (I agree the documentation is far from clear, but that's my understanding of it. I could be wrong...)

Comment: @JonSkeet still did not make any difference after making Timer static.

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine for me too. The issue got reproduced with following change in your program:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Schedule task");
        Timer time = new Timer();

        TesterClient tc = new TesterClient();
        time.schedule(tc, 0, 3000);
    }
}


class TesterClient extends TimerTask {
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("New Task!!!!");
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        init();
        this.cancel(); //-------This causes hang in execution after printing once
    }
}
```

But, not sure what could have caused this to happen without `cancel()` in your program.

Comment: well this is kind of obvious since you are cancelling the task.